# Aggregate area of geoqueryset by group in Django

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions, geodjango, django-queryset

I am trying to calculate aggregate areas for a model with a geodjango geometry field, grouped by an additional property. I did not find a function for that in the [geoqueryset api reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/), and the regular [Sum aggregate function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum) does not apply to this case.

So I tried using the "extra" argument on querysets as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()

MyModel.objects.all()\
    .extra(select={'area': 'SUM(ST_Area(geom))'})\
    .values('area', 'name')
```

This does not work and the following programming error is returned.

```
column "app_mymodel.name_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause \
or be used in an aggregate function
```

I tried several combinations of `extra`, `values` and `annotate` with these fields but was not able to get a working aggregate. If I leave away the grouping argument `names` the total area is returned successfully.

Any ideas on how can I get the area of a geometry field grouped by an additional property?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hack something together using `.values_list`, `.distinct`, `.area`, and `reduce`.

The `values_list(...).distinct()` incantation is used to get a list of unique `name` attribute values.

Next, you loop through the unique values, filter the model queryset using the unique value, and then sum the filtered QuerySet using `reduce`.  I had to use a loop (i.e. `reduce`) to sum, because `area` doesn't exist as an column in the database for use with the more conventional `.aggregate(Sum(...))` method.

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Area    
from data.models import MyGeoModel

distincts = MyGeoModel.objects.order_by('name').distinct('name').values_list('name', flat=True)

for value in distincts:
    print reduce(lambda a,x: a+x.calculated_area.sq_ft, MyGeoModel.objects.filter(name=value).area(model_att='calculated_area'), Area(0))
```